# Cocoapods 1.10.beta.2 - Unable to load contents of file list (xcfilelist)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I recently updated cocoapods to `1.10.beta.2` and my project no longer compiles, reporting the following error:

> Unable to load contents of file list: '.../Pods/Target Support
> Files/Pods-XXX/Pods-XXX-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the pods team recent switched from using the project's `objectVersion` to using the `compatibilityVersion` to decide whether or not to generate this file list, as seen in [this commit](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/commit/d4e8141261e40e3e2d9a201d627457a2c11eb545).

By bumping your compatibility version to 9.3 (or greater) and running `pod install`, the missing file should be restored.  To do so, select the project and select the desired version from the drop down list in your File Inspector.

[image: File Inspector]

Since this change is present in the pods 1.10 beta, it will probably be present in releases 1.10 and greater.